# Schedule Table Design

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design

I am working on doctor scheduler page requirement. The below is the screen for showing a usual weekdays schedule for a doctor.

[image]

1. The doctor may visit only few days on a week and only between a period of time
2. A doctor may be on leave some day. They add that entry

I need to design the database table to handle above scheduling.

I have no idea how a database table can be designed for 7 days with hours and doctors mapped.

**The most important thing is for a given week i should be able to check the doctor availability.**

I created a `DoctorLeave` table below to handle only doctor leave days

`DoctorId`, `LeaveDate`, `Comment`

But, How do i design scheduler table? Any idea/suggestions pls

Answer (score 1):

I’d go with a structure that looks like this

```
-Doctor_ID
-Patient_ID
-Activity_Start
-Activity_End 
-Activity_Type_ID
```

For activity type I’d create a lookup table that could look like this

```
Activity_Type_ID      Activity_Description


1.                     Working with patients 

2.                     Absent
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table for scheduling should be simple. All you need are doctor_id, patient_id, begin_time, end_time (both fields containing both date and time). Then your query or UI code figure out which day of the week those lie on and how to display them on a schedule table, etc.

You should create a separate table for doctor unavailability. doctor_id, leave_begins, leave_ends (both as dates and times if necessary). Once again, use your queries or UI code to figure out conflicts during appointment scheduling.

Comment: Why do i need to set doctors unavailability table? The data given to me is `When a doctor is available` If somebody ask me for a perticular time, i lookup available time and say `Sorry` if it is not available. This is the way every 1 will think :)

Comment: @Billa: You need the 'unavailability' table to ensure that you don't schedule doctors for appointments at midnight or on days where they are travelling, etc. If you query mroach's first table, there will be plenty of times when a doctor apparently is available - but isn't really.